# Analog for JQuery's .has() in angular2 BrowserDomAdapter

Tags: angular

Is there an analog for JQuery's .has() in angular2 BrowserDomAdapter or an equivalent way to implement such functionality with the methods provided?

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to make your own directive/pipe, check the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a268f5225cad9ab380494e61a10105cc9eb107e7/src/traversing.js#L23-L35)..

Answer (score 0):

There are no jQuery substitutes in BrowserDomAdapter or Angular2 at all.

You can do most of the things you can do in plain JS using BrowserDomAdapter. If you can't do something you still can fall back to direct DOM access (should be prevented for WebWorker and server-side-rendering compatibility) to have all possibilities plain JS provides.